# Getting cell tower information from a 3G modem

Tags: linux, modem, 3g

I'm trying to use a 3G modem to get a rough location by using the cell IDs and [OpenCellID](http://opencellid.org/).  The modem is a Huawei E303 (USB ID `12d1:14db`), driven by the `cdc_ether` Linux driver.

As far as I can tell, use of `cdc_ether` precludes using AT commands to list the cell IDs (at least without disconnecting from the network, reconfiguring the modem substantially, scanning for cells, reconfiguring the modem again and reconnecting).

My question is:  Is there some way of getting the list of cell IDs while connected to the network using the `cdc_ether` driver?